# Multiple conditions in one if statement in JAVA

Tags: java

Let's say I have an integer variable called X, I'd like to check if its value meets multiple conditions, I wonder if there's a way to write it like this (or similarly)

`if (x == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4)`

rather than using x again like

```
if (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4)
```

I just don't want to fill up my code if I have a lot of conditions required. Anyone knows the best way to shorten up the space for this kind of situations?

Comment: In a word -- no. Each condition must be a standard boolean condition, nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: `if (IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).anyMatch(y -> x == y))`